# How to fix typescript Error (TS2322) (Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<InputRef> | undefined' ) ? The code is below

Tags: typescript, error-handling, compiler-errors, autocomplete

I've tried to follow the source file for 'Ref', and I don't see any problem with the code, but it still shows me two issues.

1 out of 2 problems is the " Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref | undefined'  "
2 out of 2 problems are" 'autoComplete' is assigned a value but never used.  "

See the attached images below [TS2322 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAFyx.jpg)

The error message of 1 out of 2 problems:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(133, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref', which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAtt

See the attached image of the 2 out of 2 problems message below
[places-autocomplete error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEIEI.jpg)

The code:

```
import { Input } from "antd"
import React, { useRef } from "react"

const PlacesAutocomplete = () => {
  const autoCompleteRef = useRef(null)

  const autoComplete = new (window as any).google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    autoCompleteRef.current,
    { types: ["(cities)"], componentRestrictions: { country: "us" } }
  )
  return (
    <Input placeholder='Start typing or move the map' ref='autoCompleteRef' />
  )
}

export default PlacesAutocomplete
```

See the attached image of the index.d.ts file below
[index.d.ts screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMpnJ.jpg)

```
interface Attributes {
        key?: Key | null | undefined;
    }
    interface RefAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
        ref?: Ref<T> | undefined;
    }
    interface ClassAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
        ref?: LegacyRef<T> | undefined;
    }

    interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
        key: Key | null;
    }

    interface ReactComponentElement<
        T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>,
        P = Pick<ComponentProps<T>, Exclude<keyof ComponentProps<T>, 'key' | 'ref'>>
    > extends ReactElement<P, Exclude<T, number>> { }
```

The message in the terminal:

```
    10 |   )
    11 |   return (
  > 12 |     <Input placeholder='Start typing or move the map' ref='autoCompleteRef' />
       |                                                       ^
    13 |   )
    14 | }
    15 |
```

Please help.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add the code as text into your question, preferably as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the code for your reference, thanks guys!